# subsonic equalent query for this query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, subsonic3

Can someone give me an equivalent query for the following MySQL query:

```
string qry = "select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rowno, b_eventid as EventID,b_eventdata as 
                     EventData,b_machinetimestamp as MachineTime,b_hosttimestamp as HostTime";
       qry = qry + " from bm_transaction, (select @rownum := 0) r where b_terminalid=" +                      
                                 tid + " order by b_hosttimestamp desc";
          MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(qry, sqlcon);
            adp.Fill(dtLogs);
```

And my SubSonic query sample is something like this:

```
DataTable dtlogs=new DataTable();
    try{
        arithmaticdataDB db=new arithmaticdataDB();
        IDataReader drreader=db.SelectColumns("b_eventid as EventID,b_eventdata as EventData,b_machinetimestamp as MachineTime,b_hosttimestamp as HostTime")
                              .From(" bm_transaction").Where("b_terminalid").IsEqualTo(tid).OrderDesc("b_hosttimestamp").ExecuteReader();
```

How can I change the above to the equivalent of my ADO.NET query in SubSonic 3.0.0.4?
Any guidance is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the first query is raw SQL with value injection and renamed columns. The second example seems to use the SubSonic 2.x expression API.

In SubSonic 3 I mostly use ActiveRecord and Linq. Your query (very roughly) might look like:

```
var event_rows = b_transaction
  .Where(x => x.b_terminalid == tid)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.hosttimestamp)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for advising me in this case i have moved the code back to ado.net for few reasons so i may not use it as of now but sure will use some time after and then let u know the result